# GWT project and Eclipse linked resources

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I have to use a Javascript file in my GWT Project. This Javascript is in a common library project and I deploy it together with my GWT Project using ANT.

So, I have no problem in production environment: but **I cannot test it in development phase**.

I tried to create an Eclipse link to Javascript resource but seem that GWT "can't see it".
Some behavior with other kind of resources (images, css etc.).

Is it a bug or is there another way to do?

I'm using Eclipse Juno, GWT 2.5.0 and Debian 7.0.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use script tag in your project's .html file?

Comment: No, I can't. Javascript file is a common library used by many projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using some kind of source control, it usually has a way to make a link to a dependent project or file.  Simply include that link in your GWT Project, and reference the file through there.

If you can't or don't want to do it through your source control, do it through your OS.  Since you're using Linux, simply make a symbolic link to the common file/folder using `ln -s` (if you were using Windows, you'd need to run `mklink` from the command line), and reference the file that way.

In either case - source control or OS - you'll be able to see the file(s) when you refresh your project in Eclipse, and modifying one will modify the other in its own directory.

#### Edit - information on symbolic links in CVS

I haven't played with CVS in quite some time, so can't speak much about its capabilities for symbolic links.  A bit of googling said it's not supported, though there are workarounds.  One workaround is to add script files that run during checkout.  That sounds like it may still be tough to make OS-agnostic.  I did find one [site](http://dbaspot.com/configuration-management/193626-cvs-symbolic-links.html) that mentioned using module aliases to get the same result.  Maybe that will give what you need.  An excerpt from the site follows:

> One common way to handle situations like this in CVS is to alias the
>   collection in a modules file rule. -Checkout the "CVSROOT" module and
>   you'll find the "modules" file; simply change it and check it in like
>   anything else, with the exception that when you check in CVSROOT files
>   they "activate" at the same time. The example below may look a little
>   kludgy, and it is because AFAIK you can't redefine a directory and alias
>   it at the same time, sadly. I'll use a typical Java situation as its
>   package system lends itself well to this kind of thing:
>
> Real module directories are "a", "b", and "common"
>
> Directory alias for all common srouce
>   _common_src_all -d src/com/mycompany/common common/src/com/mycompany/common
>
> Full "A" project including common
>   a_all &a &_common_src_all
>
> Full "B" project including common
>   b_all &b &_common_src_all

Comment: Thank you. I hope in a more "platform independent" solution. Some colleagues use Windows and we're using CVS. CVS can't manage link; and symbolic links are Linux dependent. Why not Eclipse linked resources?

Comment: Edited with a website I found that might give you a good workaround using module aliases.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to create symbolic links using ANT (and to add them in .cvsignore). I add here a tip to other readers: Jetty doesn't work with symbolic link. It's important to add in launcher's "VM arguments": -Dorg.mortbay.util.FileResource.checkAliases=false.